# File Upload in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I am trying to upload a file in load-runner for REST API call which is working fine on postman.
I need to upload a 20 MB file which uploads perfectly well of 20MB when it is done from postman but when I am using web_submit_data, web_rest or web_custom_request in load-runner i am able to upload a file only of 16 bytes . My request looks like below:

```
web_rest("UPLOAD",
    "URL={URL}",
    "Method=POST",
    "EncType=multipart/form-data",
    "Snapshot=t2.inf",
    ITEMDATA,
    "Name=EmployeeId", "Value={EmployeeId}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=ComponentId", "Value={ComponentId}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=entityId", "Value={entityid}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=CategoryId", "Value={CategoryId}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=tagId", "Value={tagid}", ENDITEM,
    "Name=fileName", "Value=abc.doc", ENDITEM,
    "Name=attachment", "Value=C://PerfDoc2.doc", ENDITEM,
    HEADERS,
    "Name=CSRF_TOK", "Value={CSRF_TOK}", ENDHEADER,
    "Name=X-REST-API", "Value=true", ENDHEADER,
    "Name=X-Requested-With", "Value=XMLHttpRequest", ENDHEADER,
    LAST);
```

With this i am only able to upload a file of 16 bytes

Comment: Did you proxy record the POSTMAN upload, including all headers?

Comment: Since there is no application or UI involved, please can you share a way how I can proxy record the requests from POSTMAN to convert it into load runner script

Comment: Define the proxy that POSTMAN uses.  Make sure it is the recording proxy Port for LoadRunner.   Set LoadRunner to record all headers.

Then you will have a LoadRunner recording of your working Postman test

Comment: Did you try to use compress related headers while uploading the file? You can check one in postman headers.